# PHP script slow after refactoring - but microtime says it's okay

Tags: php, performance, templates

I am displaying a dynamic table that ends up looking like this:
[image: table preview]

it basically allows me to manage my mySQL fields to be editable from the website.

the model file loads the db values with one query and passes an array to the view.

The view then compiles everything into a table.

It used to be that the view file had all html tags hardcoded into it, now I've switched to where each tag is a template file, generated via [this kind of template class](http://www.broculos.net/2008/03/how-to-make-simple-html-template-engine.html#.U8sZd_ldV8F).

So I've gone from creating this table using one file with 2 nested for loops (for each row, and for each field within the row) to doing the extra layer of always making a call to my template class.

for example:

**OLD**

view.php:

```
$table_row[$index][] = '<td><input type="text" name="'.$fieldname.'"value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'"></td>';
$last_row[] = '<td><input type="text" name="'.$fieldname.'"></td>';
```

**NEW**

input_tag_template.php:

```
<input type="{@TYPE}" name="{@NAME}" value="{@VALUE}"{@ADDTL_ATTR}></input>
```

view.php:

```
$tpl_input_tag->set("NAME", $fieldname);
$tpl_input_tag->set("TYPE", 'text');
$tpl_input_tag->set("VALUE", htmlspecialchars($value));

$tpl_td_tag->set("INNER_HTML", $tpl_input_tag->output());
$table_row[$index][] = $tpl_td_tag->output();
$tpl_input_tag->set("VALUE", '');   
$tpl_td_tag->set("INNER_HTML", $tpl_input_tag->output());
$last_row[] = $tpl_td_tag->output();
```

The full code of the view can be seen [here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57490/after-refactoring-using-template-class-php-file-takes-forever-to-load-timeout)

This change has now resulted in the page taking a good 10 - 20 seconds to load, compared to the previous 2-3 seconds MAX. Sometimes I even receive an error message that it timed out after more then 30 seconds.

I realize I am making like over 100 calls to the template class, and each one involves `file_get_contents()` and `str_replace()`, so I've tried calling `microtime()` at the very beginning of my entire script, and at the very and, and then showing the difference, and it said `0.568397`. Doesn't seem too extreme to me?

If I go back to the old, less flexible version, it loads just fine.

Having this problem, I realized that this is probably not the BEST way to use the template class (making one template per tag) and probably a bit overkill - needless to say making my code much longer and more difficult to understand. Maybe I should reduce flexibility and increase the number of views/template files used instead.

That aside though, I don't understand why it suddenly takes so much longer to load, but `microtime()` doesn't indicate that...?

**How can I find out why it's so slow, find bottlenecks? How can I speed up the page load?**

Comment: PHP is a template engine, by adding a template engine to it you broken Occam's Razor ;p, the simplest solution is always best and in programming almost always faster. Basically your expecting an extra 100 steps tobe faster then just assigning to an array. From the image, that should be 1 view with data passed to it being the rows, a button is not a view, your breaking it down way too much. Every operation unless highly optimised consumes CPU cycles and memory. Run your code through xdebug.

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring the time correctly? I think you might be measuring the time for one view, not all of them.

Comment: And, for example, ... if the template is the same, ... why you load it from filesystem each time?